# Ifelse on text to create a new column in R

Tags: r, if-statement

data:

**weather**
sunny
sunny rainy
cloudy
rainy
cloudy sunny

I want to add a new column that contains a 1 if it was sunny during the day and a 0 if it was not sunny. It works for the first row of data but not on the others.

```
df$sunny <- ifelse(df$weather %in% "sunny", "1", "0")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What’s the problem? Works for me (though I’d rethink the encoding of “sunny”).

Comment: It looks like you only have one variable. If that is the case, use `grepl` instead: `ifelse(grepl(df$weather  "sunny"), "1", "0") `. Even better you don't need `ifelse`:  `as.integer(grepl(df$weather  "sunny")`.

Comment: or `grepl(df$weather, 'sunny')*1`

Comment: @Sotos You should be super wary of such “tricks” that abuse weak typing because they obscure the meaning of your code wonderfully. Be explicit.

Comment: @KonradRudolph agreed. Never really looked at it that way. Just thought it's a neat trick. Don't remember where I picked it up from but it was a well received answer here in SO...

Comment: @lmo thanks! It worked with     `df$sunny <- ifelse(grepl("sunny", df$weather), "1", "0")`